# Where's he taking the number from? Custom numeric keyboard (Android Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a small program that I have looked for of example where a numerical personalized keyboard is created in which I have several doubts:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Editable
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        initViews()
    }

    private fun initViews() {
        t9_key_0.setOnClickListener(this)
        t9_key_1.setOnClickListener(this)
        t9_key_2.setOnClickListener(this)
        t9_key_3.setOnClickListener(this)
        t9_key_4.setOnClickListener(this)
        t9_key_5.setOnClickListener(this)
        t9_key_6.setOnClickListener(this)
        t9_key_7.setOnClickListener(this)
        t9_key_8.setOnClickListener(this)
        t9_key_9.setOnClickListener(this)
        t9_key_backspace.setOnClickListener(this)
        t9_key_clear.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {

        if (v?.tag != null && "number_button" == v.tag) {

            password_field.append((v as TextView).text)
            return

        }
        when (v?.id) {

            R.id.t9_key_clear -> {

                password_field.text = null

            }
            R.id.t9_key_backspace -> {

                val editable: Editable = password_field.text
                val charCount = editable.length

                if (charCount > 0) {

                    editable.delete(charCount - 1, charCount)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These are my styles:

```
<style name="keyboard_row">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/keyboard_divider</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:showDividers">beginning|middle|end</item>
</style>

<style name="keyboard_button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/keyboard_button_bg</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge</item>
</style>

<style name="keyboard_number_button" parent="keyboard_button">
    <item name="android:tag">number_button</item>
</style>
```

And this is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_margin="20dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dp">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password_field"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:background="#eeeeee"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/keyboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:divider="@drawable/keyboard_divider"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:showDividers="beginning|middle|end">

    <TableRow style="@style/keyboard_row">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t9_key_1"
            style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
            android:text="@string/number_one" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t9_key_2"
            style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
            android:text="@string/number_two" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t9_key_3"
            style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
            android:text="@string/number_three" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow style="@style/keyboard_row">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t9_key_4"
            style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
            android:text="@string/number_four" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t9_key_5"
            style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
            android:text="@string/number_five" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t9_key_6"
            style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
            android:text="@string/number_six" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow style="@style/keyboard_row">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t9_key_7"
            style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
            android:text="@string/number_seven" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t9_key_8"
            style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
            android:text="@string/number_eight" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t9_key_9"
            style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
            android:text="@string/number_nine" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow style="@style/keyboard_row">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t9_key_clear"
            style="@style/keyboard_button"
            android:text="@string/btn_clear"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t9_key_0"
            style="@style/keyboard_number_button"
            android:text="@string/number_zero" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/t9_key_backspace"
            style="@style/keyboard_button"
            android:text="@string/btn_backspace"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

First of all the first doubt I had was about the tag. I don't know if I'm right but as I've read, these are used for when we have many buttons with the same onClick event, they are all grouped with the same tag and so we do not have to write the same code many times. What I can not understand, is where is capturing the number that corresponds to that button, ie: how does Android Studio know that when I press the button that has 1, should place that 1? I don't see any line of code where I say it, or at least not something I know, that's why I come to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is the line

```
password_field.append((v as TextView).text)
```

I would need more of the code or the layout file etc. but from the code that you have posted, this seems to be the line that would do it.

Comment: I've edited my question with a few more classes. I also think that's the line that handles the text set, but I can not understand how it is able to know that in that TextView there is a 1, a 2, and so on.

Comment: The line above is taking the text from the button that is clicked and appending it to the password field. In your layout file you have the text of each TextView set as android:text="@string/number_one". I assume this string refers to a character "1" in the Strings.xml file.  So when you click on a button, it is taking the text of the button, which is in the strings.xml file.